# Image gets cropped while replacing image in google docs using google doc api

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to replace the image using **google doc api**. Image is replaced but it takes the dimensions of previous and so gets cropped.

I also tried by providing height and width but it didn't work.
When I reset the image manually in google doc then the full image is showing in doc and after reset image, its height and width can be changed accordingly. But google doc API did not provide an option to reset image.

Here is a little code which replaces the image in a Google doc :

```
"replaceImage": {
                "imageObjectId": IMAGE_ID",
                "uri": REPLACED_IMAGE_URL,
                "imageReplaceMethod": IMAGE_REPLACE_METHOD,
               }
```

Is there any possible way to replace the image so that it can replace the previous image properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to avoid cropping when using the `replaceImage` request. As it can be seen [in the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#ImageReplaceMethod), the only valid value for `imageReplaceMethod` is `CENTER_CROP`, which "Scales and centers the image to fill the bounds of the original image. **The image may be cropped in order to fill the original image's bounds**. The rendered size of the image will be the same as that of the original image.".

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: When I tried to delete the image using **DeletePositionedObjectRequest**, API returned errror: 
    **"deletePositionedObject": {
          "objectId": OBJECT_ID
        },**
    
    **Error: Invalid requests[6].deletePositionedObject: No positioned object with ID : OBJECT_ID**
    
    And while deleting image there can be one more issue, the object id of image will change. Then how it will possible to add image on the same position without object id of image.

Comment: @NishiLamba If `OBJECT_ID` is not valid, this probably means that your image is not a positioned image but an inline image. In this case, I'll delete the proposed workaround from my answer since this is not useful for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the "reset image" worked for me after replacing the image. It resets the size of the image you just uploaded to the original instead of keeping at the size of the previous pic. Remember, upload new image, then click the reset icon [see example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CetIf.png) Reset icon only shows when replacing image. Your icon may look different. Use cursor to hover icons until you find reset icon.